# Passing Jenkins credentials through Node JS to shell script

Tags: node.js, shell, curl, jenkins

My workflow goes like this :
I have a custom node module installed in my Jenkins slave that calls a few shell scripts . I would like to pass the credentials obtained through the `credentials()`

method provided by Jenkins declarative pipeline syntax.
What happens right now is that when I pass the username and password environment variables provided by the pipeline to the node module which in turn passes the arguments to the shell script which is used to CURL a file to a remote location 
I get bad credentials failure.
But if I do the same thing by simply calling the shell script whithout passing thorugh the node_module the same creds work fine.
Is there any workaround for this behaviour ? I am just trying to understand here

Thanks in advance